# Picker View only selects first object from NSArray in text box

Tags: objective-c, ios5, textbox, xcode4.2, uipickerview

Im trying to learn how to select an object from a picker view to display in a TextBox, six hours in I thought id finally cracked but no. It works, but I can only get the first item in my NSArray to display in my text box.

`Select` being my picker, `arrstatus` is my NSArray, `text1` is my text box.

Using a button to get my value:  under IBAction:

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
  [text1 resignFirstResponder];
```

rest of code:

.h

```
@interface pick5 : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,     UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

 {

UIPickerView *select;

NSArray *arrStatus;


}
```

.m

```
UIPickerView *select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
select.delegate = self;
select.dataSource = self;
[select setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
text1.inputView = select;

arrStatus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bs88", @"bs60898", @"Memphis",      @"California", @"Seattle",@"London",@"Paris", nil];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
//One column
  return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
//set number of rows
return arrStatus.count;
  }

 -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
//set item per row
return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];













[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[self setText1:nil];
[self setResign:nil];
[self setText2:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}





 - (IBAction)resign:(id)sender {


NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
[text1 resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

im also getting yellow warning triangles `local decalration of "select" hides instance variable`

Comment: Have you tried logging selectedRow (in your IBAction) to see if it always returns 0 no matter which row you select in the picker view? Are you still getting the local declaration error, because I don't see anything in the code you posted that should cause that?

Comment: No local declaration error now.   Will try logging and report back.

Comment: Sorted the instance variable error was causing the problem.  Thanks for helping confirm the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your warning in yellow color change the following line of code in your .m file.

```
UIPickerView *select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

replace above with below:

```
select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

because you have already declared uipicker* select in .h file.

Comment: Thats also sorted the other problem! Thanks for your advice